# JGit/EGit Loading of translation bundle failed en_US

Tags: java, locale, bundle, egit, jgit

I am running the following code in a JUnit test to test fetching a git repository.  I'm writing a test for each of the basic functionality i need from JGit so that then i can implement them in my application.  The problem is that i keep getting the following error on the git.fetch() call below:

```
Loading of translation bundle failed for [org.eclipse.jgit.JGitText, en_US]
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TranslationBundleLoadingException: Loading of translation bundle failed for [org.eclipse.jgit.JGitText, en_US]
```

The code sample is below.  I verified that the repository paths and everything seems correct.  If i put a breakpoint on the fetch call and then run the same command in MSysGit it works.

```
  try {
         String remoteName = "origin";
         URIish uri = new URIish(repository.getRepositoryDirectory());
         saveRemote(repository2.getRepository(), uri, remoteName);
         Git git = repository.getGit();
         FetchResult r = git.fetch().setRemote(remoteName).call();
         assertNotNull("Did not get any result from fetch.", r);
      } catch (JGitInternalException ex) {
         fail("Failed to do fetch. " + ex.getMessage());
      } catch (InvalidRemoteException ex) {
         fail("Failed to do fetch. " + ex.getMessage());
      } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
         fail("Failed to do fetch. " + ex.getMessage());
      }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured this out.  I had to copy the file JGitText.properties from the binary distribution into the same package in the source code, rename it to JGitText_en_US.properties, and add a whole bunch of properties to it manually that the code used in JGitText.java but were not defined in JGitText.properties.

I searched through the entire source code and all binary files and related docs and found no reference to these new properties, or the properties file being created anywhere.  I don't know why the devs don't have localization files in the source code or at least a way to generate then through a build file or something.  I mean they must manually have to add them into their source code and just not commit it.

Anyway this was a very annoying issue, there was no documentation on it anywhere on the net (that google revealed anyway) so I thought i would share this as it might help others who ran into the same problem.

Comment: more and more i'm regretting using this package :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but my fix was a little different.  In my case, the problem was related to the OSGI classloader.

Here's a commit that fixes the issue:
https://github.com/diffplug/jgit/commit/3bcc69bde5567ec57ccd6bd065ded0db49f810fb

And here's the rationale behind it:
[Loading a ResourceBundle within an OSGi bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598351/loading-a-resourcebundle-within-an-osgi-bundle)